# Show empty string when date field is 1/1/1900

Tags: sql-server, datetime, case

I'm querying a database like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE WHEN CreatedDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN '' ELSE CreatedDate END AS CreatedDate
FROM LitHoldDetails
```

lhd.CreatedDate is a DateTime field and is non-nullable. I want to display an empty string if the field is the minimum date (1/1/1900), but my CASE statement doesn't work; CreatedDate displays 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 in my query when that value is in the database. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you use a `CASE` expression (not *statement*) you have to be aware of data type precedence. In this case you can't just set a `DATETIME` to an empty string. Try it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '');
```

One workaround is to present your date as a string:

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate) = '1900-01-01' -- to account for accidental time
  THEN ''
  ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), CreatedDate, 120)
    + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), CreatedDate, 108)
END
```

Or you could fiddle with the presentation stuff where it belongs, at the presentation tier.

Here is an example that works exactly as you seem to want:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(CreatedDate DATETIME);

INSERT @d SELECT '19000101' UNION ALL SELECT '20130321';

SELECT d = CASE WHEN CreatedDate = '19000101'
  THEN ''
  ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), CreatedDate, 120)
    + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), CreatedDate, 108)
END FROM @d;
```

Results:

```
d
-------------------
                    <-- empty string
2013-03-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not trying to convert CreatedDate to an empty string, I'm trying to test for its value and output either its value or an empty string. I've tried to do this at the presentation layer as well, but the value test isn't working. When I try your CASE statement, I still get 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 when the date is 1/1/1900.

Comment: @Melanie But you are trying to convert an empty string to a datetime when you did this: `CASE WHEN something THEN '' ELSE SomeDateTime END`

Comment: @Melanie output as a string = `CONVERT` to a string, even if you didn't explicitly say `CONVERT`. You can't just magically change a valid `datetime` to a string.

Comment: Aaron - Okay, now I understand. I had no idea this was what was going on under the hood. It's working now if I just test for the value and use CAST if I'm actually outputting the date. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

```
select  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), WorkingDate,121),'') from uv_Employee
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this code

```
(case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDate, 103) = '01/01/1900' then '' else CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), CreatedDate, 121) end) as Date_Resolved
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `CAST` your data as a `VARCHAR()` instead of explicitly `CONVERT`ing your data you can simply

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(CreatedDate AS VARCHAR(20)),'Jan  1 1900 12:00AM','')
```

The `CAST` will automatically return your Date then as `Jun 18 2020 12:46PM` fix length strings formats which you can additionally `SUBSTRING()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CAST(CreatedDate  AS VARCHAR(20)),'Jan  1 1900 12:00AM',''),1,11)
```

**Output**

```
Jun 18 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside of query, no need to create extra variables.

```
CASE WHEN CreatedDate = '19000101' THEN '' WHEN CreatedDate =
'18000101' THEN ''  ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), CreatedDate, 120) + ' ' +
CONVERT(CHAR(8), CreatedDate, 108) END as 'Created Date'
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Two nitpicks. (1) Best not to use string literals for column alias - that is deprecated. (2) Just use style 120 to get the same value.

```
    CASE 
      WHEN CreatedDate = '19000101' THEN '' 
      WHEN CreatedDate = '18000101' THEN '' 
      ELSE Convert(varchar(19), CreatedDate, 120)
    END AS [Created Date]
```

Comment: While I agree with nitpick 1, where is anyone on this page using a string literal for a column alias?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution that covers both min (1/1/1900) and max (6/6/2079) dates:

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDate, 120), '1900-01-01'), '2079-06-06'), '').
```

Whatever solution you use, you should do a conversion of your date (or datetime) field to a specific format to bulletproof against different default server configurations.

See CAST and CONVERT on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simpler method that worked. ISNULL Nested CAST function can remove 1900-1-1 value if data is NULL

```
ISNULL(CAST(CAST(<<DateColumn>> AS DATE) AS Varchar),' ') [<<Date Column Name>>]
```