# How do I select a date field when NULL is present?

Tags: datetime

I am trying to select date fields in my query using ISNULL, but when there is a NULL value rather than an actual date it defaults to 1900-01-01 00:00:00 as a result.  Basically, I want nothing displayed if the date field is null, and to display what is populated there when it is anything other than null.

Select isnull(date_field,'') 
from table_name

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which database you're using.  You might want to try:

select if(isnull(date_field) or date_field = '1900-01-01 00:00:00', null, date_field) from table_name;

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using MS SQL Server 2008. I am trying to build a report that has several date columns/fields in it. All of the fields I am selecting in my select line populate just fine with isnull(column,''), essentially making it blank if the value is NULL, except the date fields.  Maybe converting the date fields to a different data type?

Comment: Check out this question: [Show empty string when date field is 1/1/1900](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554369/show-empty-string-when-date-field-is-1-1-1900)

Comment: As a follow up to this, I was able to use the following pulled from the above link and it worked:

CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, CreatedDate) = '1900-01-01' -- to account for accidental time
  THEN ''
  ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), CreatedDate, 120)
    + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), CreatedDate, 108)
END 

The field I was converting was a smalldatetime field.  When I try and use this on just a date data type field, it does not work.  Is there a way to use the same idea for date data type?

Comment: I would post a separate question with specific examples of how it works for a smalldatetime and how you would like it to work for a date.  You'll get more answers if you tag your question appropriately.  Try tagging it with "sql" and "sql-server".

Answer (score 0):

Google translator is well rounded understanding of place you do not know English.

null, then the query if it excluded

=> SELECT DATE_FIELD FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_FIELD IS NOT NULL

If you want the default value to be null

=> SELECT NVL(DATE_FIELD, '1900-01-01') FROM TABLE_NAME

=> SELECT NVL(DATE_FIELD, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS')) FROM TABLE_NAME