# Blank values in Date column returning as 1900/01/01 on running SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, replace

The column [PAYOFF DATE] has some blank values and some values in mm/dd/yy format.

I have to replace '/' with '-' and return the date as yyyy-mm-dd. The below query is doing it. The problem is that for all blank values, I am getting results as 1900-01-01.

Is it possible to replace 1900-01-01 with null and return other valid date values as is in yyyy-mm-dd format?

I am using SQL Server.

```
SELECT
cast(replace(a.[PAYOFF DATE],'/','-') as date) 
FROM MTG a
```

Comment: This may put you on the right track. You can convert the Datetime to a string since datetime cannot return an empty value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554369/show-empty-string-when-date-field-is-1-1-1900

Comment: @sealz - I looked up that link already but in my case, I have to do two things, first replace '/' with '-' and then return NULL when date is in 1900-01-01 hence I am facing problem performing these two operations together in one statement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You dont need to do the string manipulation as you have shown in your question. If you have dates stored in `mm/dd/yyyy` format just cast it as DATE.

```
SELECT cast(a.[PAYOFF DATE] AS DATE) 
FROM MTG a
```

For `1900-01-01` values, since you are converting from a string data type to Date, String datatype can have Empty strings but Date datatype cannot have empty date values, It can have either a date value or `NULL` value.

Therefore you need to convert the empty string to nulls before you convert it to date. 1900-01-01 is just a default value sql server puts in for you because Date datatype cannot have an empty value.

You can avoid having this sql server default value by doing something like this.

```
SELECT cast(NULLIF(a.[PAYOFF DATE],'') AS DATE) 
FROM MTG a
```

Answer (score 3):

CASE WHEN [Pay Date] = '' THEN NULL ELSE  TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [Pay Date]) END