# How to pass blank value to date or time data type field while calling api

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, date-conversion

Currently I am working on the project where I want to pass the blank value to date data type field in api and in return want blank or null value to that field.

For ex.
xyz.org/v1/serviceUpdate?RecordID=103&Name=Aazad+Hind1&Age=75&DOB=****&token=retretretrt222343

What should I pass in **** place so that empty value get passed to DOB field.
I try with NULL value but it gave me the following error
SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

while hitting the below url

xyz.org/v1/serviceUpdate?RecordID=103&Name=Aazad+Hind1&Age=75&DOB=&token=retretretrt222343

It is storing 01/01/1900 default value.I want blank or null value instead of default value in response.

Anyone know about how to achieved this without doing any changes in third party api let me know

Comment: What is the exact type of the `DOB` field?

Comment: DOB field type is date

Comment: Is that possible that you can do : SELECT cast(NULLIF(tabA.[DOB],'') AS DATE)  
FROM Table tabA (Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973154/blank-values-in-date-column-returning-as-1900-01-01-on-running-select-statement)

Comment: not possible from my end.because I am calling third party api

Comment: Is the code of `serviceUpdate` is yours or third party?

Comment: third party.I just have to call there api and have to see the pushed data into their dashboard side

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when your DOB field in the database is defined as `DEFAULT NULL` as shown below.

```
DOB date DEFAULT NULL
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13934665/5644934