# I can't change default date in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, date

Hi Everyone I have two problems with my code below :
first, I want to add TextDate to SQL Quire but it takes the default value (01-01-1990), how can remove the default value?
Second, I want to add a Placeholder in DropDownList and remove the default value ( i use             ddlyearpublication.Items.Add(("Select").ToString()); to look like Placeholder but it's not the efficient way)

Asp Code :

```
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtContentTitle" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Title "></asp:TextBox> 
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" class="form-control " placeholder="Type "></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" class="form-control " placeholder="Lang"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" class="form-control " placeholder="name"></asp:TextBox>

                  <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radiobtn" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" class="  mt-5">
                      <asp:ListItem Value="x">x</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Value="y">y</asp:ListItem>

                  </asp:RadioButtonList>


                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Class=" form-control col-md-10  mt-5 dd" BackColor="White" placeholder="Date1"></asp:TextBox>
                  <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="Calendar1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextDate"  Format="dd-MM-yyyy"></cc1:CalendarExtender>

                  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyearpublication" runat="server" class=" form-control col-md-10 mt-5 " Height="30" >  </asp:DropDownList> <%--Years--%>


                  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search " class="btn col-md-10 mt-5" BackColor="#5b9b7d" ForeColor="White" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
               <asp:Button ID="cmdClear" runat="server"  Text="Clear "  class="btn col-md-10 mt-5" BackColor="#5b9b7d" ForeColor="White"  />
```

C# :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

            if (IsPostBack == false)
            { BindListView();}

            ddlyearpublication.Items.Add(("Select").ToString());

            for (int Year = 1990; Year <= DateTime.Now.Year; Year++)
            {ddlyearpublication.Items.Add(Year.ToString());}

private void BindListView()
        {
            string qu="";
            string conString = CRUD.conStr; 
            string format = radiobtn.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string yearOfPublication = ddlyearpublication.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string decisionDate = TextDate.Text; //How Can I add Date Below ??

            if (txtContentTitle.Text != "" || TextBox1.Text != "" || TextBox2.Text != "" || TextBox3.Text != "" || TextBox4.Text != "" || TextBox5.Text != "" || format  != "" )
            {

            if (yearPublication.Contains("Select")){
            qu = " select * from Mytable where Title LIKE N'%" + txtContentTitle.Text + "%'  and 
             Type LIKE N'%" + TextBox3.Text + "%' and language LIKE N'%" + TextBox4.Text + "%' and 
              name LIKE N'%" + TextBox5.Text + "%' " +
                    "and format LIKE N'%" + format + "%'    "; // remove yearPublication HERE
             } 



              else{
                  qu = " select * from Mytable where Title LIKE N'%" + txtContentTitle.Text + "%'  
                  and Type LIKE N'%" + TextBox3.Text + "%' and language LIKE N'%" + TextBox4.Text 
                   + "%' and name LIKE N'%" + TextBox5.Text + "%' " +
                    "and format LIKE N'%" + format + "%' and yearOfPublication ='" + 
                         yearPublication + "'   ";}



 } 
else { 
 qu = "select * from Mytable "; }
```

Comment: In your select query you can remove dafault date. [Check for removing default date from SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554369/show-empty-string-when-date-field-is-1-1-1900)

Comment: Please consider using SQL parameters. This code is good candidate for SQL injections. Type LIKE N'%" + TextBox3.Text + "%' should become Type LIKE N'%'+@textbox2param+'%'